# How to use TensorFlow tf.print with non capital p?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have some TensorFlow code in a custom loss function.

I'm using `tf.Print(node, [debug1, debug2], "print my debugs: ")`

It works fine but TF says `tf.Print` is depricated and will be removed once i update TensorFlow and that i should be using `tf.**p**rint()`, with small p.

I've tried using `tf.print` the same way i would `tf.Print()` but it's not working. Once i fit my model in Keras, i get an error. unlike `tf.Print`, `tf.print` seems to take in anything `**kwargs`, so what am i suppose to give it? and unlike `tf.Print` it do not seem to return something that i can inject into the computational graph.

It's really difficult to search because all the information online is about `tf.Print()`.

Can someone explain how to use `tf.print()`?

Edit: Example code

```py
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = K.mean(...)
    print_no_op = tf.Print(loss, [loss, y_true, y_true.shape], "Debug output: ")
    return print_no_op

model.compile(loss=custom_loss)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both the documentation of [`tf.print`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print) and [`tf.Print`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print) mention that `tf.print` returns an operation with no output, so it cannot be evaluated to any value. The syntax of `tf.print` is meant to be more similar to Python's builtin [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print). In your case, you could use it as follows:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = K.mean(...)
    print_op = tf.print("Debug output:", loss, y_true, y_true.shape)
    with tf.control_dependencies([print_op]):
        return K.identity(loss)
```

Here [`K.identity`](https://keras.io/backend/#identity) creates a new tensor identical to `loss` but with a control dependency to `print_op`, so evaluating it will force executing the printing operation. Note that Keras also offers [`K.print_tensor`](https://keras.io/backend/#print_tensor), although it is less flexible than `tf.print`.

Comment: How would i use that in a custom loss function using Keras?
would i just include the print_op variable in the some calculation like i would with tf.Print?

Comment: @CodeMonkey No, `print_op` does not have any value, it only really make sense to use it with `tf.control_dependencies` to ensure it gets executed (I changed a bit the code example). If you post some of your code maybe it's easier to explain how to make the change.

Comment: I've added an example function. Note I'm using Keras, so i'm not really sure how that fits into the inner workings of TensorFlow. The print_no_op would return the loss variable once evaluated but also print the debug output in the list.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it first thing when i get home, and get back to you :)

Comment: Good discussion here: https://github.com/tensorflow/community/pull/14/files.  It seems tf.print was created for eager execution and this added pain for graph execution was just the cost.  Presumably, you aren't supposed to need print statements once you are in graph mode.

Answer (score 2):

Just a little addition to jdehesa's excellent answer:

tf.tuple can be used to couple the print operation with another operation, which will then run with that operation whichever session executes the graph. Here's how that is done:

```
print_op = tf.print(something_you_want_to_print)
some_tensor_list = tf.tuple([some_tensor], control_inputs=[print_op])
# Use some_tensor_list[0] instead of any_tensor below.
```